# I am using Utopia but I don't like the italic. Which free fonts have an italic version that goes well with utopia?

Tags: formatting

I am using Utopia (11 pt) for a non fiction book and I like it. But I don't like the italic, the quotes are not very readable. I tried many fonts in LibreOffice, but I didn't find a good match yet. I am planning to self publish on a budget and I would like to use a font that is free and is widely available. Which free fonts have an italic version that have a good appearance alongside utopia?

Comment: I already searched a lot through all the search engines and I found only a lot of spam. I already found typewolf, but there I could find any useful comment.

Comment: There are a few things that are unclear about your question: (1) What do you mean with "the quotes are not very readable"? Do you mean quotations? Quotations aren't conventionally given in italics, they are surrounded by quotation marks. Italics are only used for emphasis, foreign words and such. (2) Why does the font have to be "widely available"? Are you publishing an ebook? If you want an ebook to look the same for all readers, you need to include your font in your ebook. And you will need the right to redistribute the font. (3) Do you want to mix the fonts in the body text?!? Don't!

Comment: (4) In what way is the italic text "not very readable"? The [italic sample on Adobe's website](https://fonts.adobe.com/fonts/utopia) looks perfectly legible to me.

Answer (score 0):

I've been writing mostly in the font E. B. Garamond. It looks similar to Utopia.